# localhost doesnot work with xampp

Tags: xampp

Maybe it is asked several times before but I couldn't get any solution. I have installed xampp in my computer. I have changed httpd.conf and httpd-ssl.conf for "port 80" and "443" troubles. Now the control panel shows that, Apache and MySql is running fine. But http://localhost is not working. Shows Not Found in my browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try this first:

1. Turn off skype, and all other applications that are running and then turn on the server
2. make sure that the server works as default installation (with all apps closed in first step)

Comment: There is no skype in my PC.

Comment: as i mentioned, all other apps too

Comment: Where shall I find those apps. It sounds a little bit complicated.

Comment: No. My system uses Port 80. So I had to change the port and then the control panel shows the apache and mysql is running fine. But localhost is not found till now.

Comment: try 127.0.0.1 and see

Answer (score 0):

Oh...I wrote http://localhost on my address bar. It did not work. Then I wrote http://localhost:8081(the port number which I changed) and it worked nicely.